# jQuery code looks inefficient, can you help? Replacing text in navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

What I am trying to do is loop through a list within a specific ID and replace each of the terms with a predifined list of terms
i.e.

- Home > Homer
- Dave > David
- Check > Checkmate

The code I have to achieve this is as follows

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#SomeID li").find(".menu-item-text").each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        text = text.replace("Home", "Homer");
        text = text.replace("Dave", "David");
        text = text.replace("Check", "Check Mate");
        $(this).text(text);
      });
    });
```

I assume that this can be done by queing up all my replaceable terms in an array and then searching the text once, replacing the terms as it hits them. However, try as I might, this is not happening at all, the above is the only way I can get it to work and it just looks wrong.

Edit - It's worth noting I have around 40 words to replace hence it needs to be efficient.

Comment: What "looks wrong"?  JQuery is written in JavaScript (in fact you could learn something by reading the code).  Reinventing the wheel is a common trait, and a bad one.

Comment: No I wrote this by "reading" lots of posts on doing similar sort of stuff but none had the complete picture, I am just asking if there's a better way.

Comment: As in, this is not a cut and paste job, at first I figured out how to find the items with the .click then I figured out how to get the text within the list and then how to replace it. Taking me roughly 4 hours this afternoon. I wish I was joking.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PgnL6/3/

Comment: Yatin, I appreciate your advice and in an ideal world I would love to play with my code and learn for myself, unfortunately I am not that 15 year old who has all the time in the world like I used to be, 4 hours is a long time for someone that doesn't have 5 minutes. I have put the time in and hit a brick wall hence my post here, not trying to become a jQuery or JavaScript master, just solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency when you are just starting out.  First learn the language, then learn to write efficient code.  Here is an alternative solution:

```
$(function(){
    var initialWords = ["Home", "Dave", "Check"];
    var replacementWords = ["Homer", "David", "Check Mate"];

    $("#SomeID li").each(function(){
        var listItem = $(this);
        var wordIndex = initialWords.indexOf(listItem.text());

        if(wordIndex > -1) {
            listItem.text(replacementWords[wordIndex]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.indexOf` won't work in <IE9](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.indexOf). I didn't see anything in the post about browser support; just pointing this out...

Comment: Its a painfully slow process thanks to banks and other institutions that are terrified of updating. I still support IE6 for some of my clients and check [the IE6 coundown site](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) every quarter or so. At the risk of starting a debate, after seeing IE10, I'm optimistic for IE's future.

Comment: Why are you replacing the whole text with the `replacementWord` not only the piece where you've found the `initialWord`?